# how to disable rails/unicorn default requests log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, unicorn

We have a **rails** app(v5.2.6) running inside a **unicorn**.
we are bombarded with log msgs like the following:

```
24.33.33.243, 12.0.52.41 - - [26/Jun/2022:13:43:39 +0000] "GET /our_path HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0078
```

No idea where this log is coming from? its bombarding our log and I must find a way to filter it.
We have a custom Rails.logger, where we also filter some msg that applies to some regexs, the problem is that this msg gets to the log from another place